# Web API to support multiple SignUp & Sign In Policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

We have an native app & SPA applications, both will use different SignUp & Sign in policies. The authentication from the Web API is working only from any one application only whatever is passed in the below configuration,

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com",
  "ClientId": "<web-app-application-id>",
  "Domain": "<your-b2c-domain>",
  **"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/<your-sign-up-in-policy>",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<your-sign-up-in-policy>"**

}
```

How to pass both the applications SignUpSignInPolicyId to authenticate in the .Net core Web API ?

I tried to pass other policies adding from add policy method as below

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy("B2C_DEMO__Native", policy => policy.RequireScope("test.read"));
}

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm in exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Multiple authentication schemes](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/multiple-authentication-schemes#multiple-authentication-schemes).

- In appsettings.json you may have 2 authentication schemes:

{

"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com",
"ClientId": "fdb91ff5-5ce6-41f3-bdbd-8267c817015d",
"Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
"EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile", // Optional profile editing policy
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc-b2c",
"ClientSecret": "",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi"
}

```
{
    "AzureAdB2C2": {
        "Instance": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com",
        "ClientId2": "fdb91ff5-5ce6-41f3-bdbd-8267c817015d", //2nd Application
        "Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId2": "b2c_2_susi",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile", // Optional profile editing policy
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc-b2c",
        "ClientSecret": "",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath2": "/signout/B2C_2_susi"
    }
```

- Similarly in [Startup.c](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/multiple-authentication-schemes#startupcs)s in ConfigureServices, we have two
  sections for .AddAuthentication, one for AzureAdB2C1 and one for
  AzureAdB2C2. Please note that .AddAuthentication() has no default
  scheme defined.

Thanks